# Setting title on NSMenuItem, without effect

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmenuitem, nsmenu

I'm getting an `NSMenuItem` from the `Main Menu`, with the code here : [Getting NSMenuItem of NSMenu tree by title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852032/getting-nsmenuitem-of-nsmenu-tree-by-title)

However, something strange happens :

- An `NSMenuItem` connected with an action : When using the sender
  property (`NSMenuItem`) and setting the title, **it works**.
- **BUT :** When getting    the item with the function above and set the title,
  the NSMenuItem's    title does change, but the change is NOT
  reflected in the menu it    belongs to.

What am I doing wrong? (I'm sure this one is really stupid... )

```
NSMenuItem* mi = [[core mainMenu] getItemWithPath:@"View" tag:PP_MENU_TAG_STATUSBAR];
[mi setTitle:@"newTitle"];
NSLog(@"mi : %@",[mi title]);

// mi changes, but no changes take effect in the mainMenu
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would forget the 
 *Getting NSMenuItem of NSMenu tree by title*  code and just connect each menu in IB.

Then use the *setTitle* on it when needed

UPDATE*

(see comments)
It took me awhile to figure out why even my test one was not working!!. I had put in a attributed title  within IB.

[image]

So when I later used *setTitle*. The property was being set but the actual displayed menu was overridden by the attributed title.

Removing the attributed title from IB. fixed this. And *setTitle* works as expected.

Also I have never used attributed title before. And I just pasted in some formatted coloured text in the IB attributed title. And the menu item was the same in colour and font.

Which I have always wanted to be able to do but thought was not possible.

And doing it programmatically is easy.

```
 NSMutableAttributedString * string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"newTestMenu"];
    [string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[NSColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(0,string.length)];

    [_testMenu setAttributedTitle:string];
```

Comment: This works (I suppose); but, what about the above? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is the tag:PP_MENU_TAG_STATUSBAR]  part?. You do not have that in the method name!

Comment: Well, ok... I admit it - for one particular sub-subcase, I had to declare a Tag for one of the menu items... so I created an appropriate function (`getItemWithPath:tag:` - pretty much the same as the other one) + define `PP_MENU_TAG_STATUSBAR`(=1)). Pffff... It really gets too complex... I've started to think that I should do it your way...

Comment: Well, outlets don't work either... Great... I'll probably have to deal with `validateMenuItem:`, etc although I'm not sure how...

Comment: It took me awhile to figure out why even my test one was not working!!. See update.